# Stripe - Is it safe to send intent ID to the client upon payment completion?

Tags: javascript, security, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I'm working on a payment completion page, and I'd also like a way to "customize" the page based on the unique transaction (such as generating a link to the purchased item, etc.) For that, I believe I'll need some sort of way to ID each payment. I've also seen in an example project that stripe sends the client secret and intent ID to the completion page, so is potentially giving anyone read access to payment intent IDs safe?

**Edit:**
Just realized Stripe's auto-redirect on completion automatically puts the client secret and intent ID on the completion page's URL, so I guess my question becomes - would it be safe to use the intent IDs to identify specific items in my app? (i.e. anyone would be able to see any intent ID; would attackers be able to do anything with them?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's safe, and client_secret is already available in client-side in [the step you create PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-create-intent) and before confirming them.

It's totally safe to have it again in client-side. You can then use [retrievePaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/retrieve_payment_intent) to retrieve *a subset of information* about the transaction. On server-side, the same Retrieve Payment Intent API will returns the full transaction information.